# Translate jQuery code to CSS or LESS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

Is it possible to translate this code from jQuery to CSS or LESS?

```
$('li').mouseover(function() {
    if ($('li ul li ul li:hover').length) {
        $('li ul li ul li:hover').css('background', 'red');
    } else if ($('li ul li:hover').length) {
        $('li ul li:hover').css('background', 'red');
    } else {
        $('li:hover').css('background', 'red');
    }
});
$('li').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'transparent');
});
```

This code is used to hover the elements in a list like here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u4cLv5f3/)

Comment: we are not hero at puzzle solution. clarify the needs with html and your tried css

Comment: Also post your html code

Comment: I added an example. When mouse over item => the item and all its children are colored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, you want a pure CSS solution (without jQuery).

Well, it's possible.

The problem is that using a background on the `li:hover` will also color the children. But when hovering the children, the hover also effects the parent `li`.

So you'll need to wrap the text in a `<span>`:

```css
li span {
  display: block;
}
li span:hover,
li span:hover~ul {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li>
    <span>Group</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Item 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Item 2.1</span></li>
          <li><span>Item 2.2</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since on hovering of every li color is same

```
li {
    background: transparent;
}
li:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

The above code is more than enough (according to my knowledge).

in scss we can write the same as

```
li {
   background: transparent;

   &:hover {
     background: red;
   }
}
```

i need to check if there will be any difference in LESS.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (obviously it's the same in Less, what could be different for such trivial almost pure CSS code?).

Comment: Thanks.. I had a small doubt that's what haven't confirmed the same.

Comment: We need to add span tag, if we need to get result as in given jsfiddle and the simplified code will be `li {
 span {
  &:hover, &:hover~ul {
   background: red;
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to change a list to red when hovered.

so:

```
li{background-color:transparent;}
li:hover{background-color:#FF0000;}
```

But I would put in in a class to contain it.

```
.li-container li{background-color:transparent;}
.li-container li:hover{background-color:#FF0000;}
```

if you want it purely in css then.

```
li ul li ul li,li ul li,li{background-color:transparent;}
li ul li ul li:hover,li ul li:hover,li:hover{background-color:#FF0000;}
```